# Paginate code for print

Tags: css, printing, pagination, jquery-pagination

Okay I'm wondering whether there is a way to tell the printer when to create a page-break when printing a HTML page? There must be something, cross-browser compatible, that allows me to do this.

An example would be to create a page break before every element with a class of 'mainHeading'.

Can anybody shed some light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify where to put page breaks by using CSS `page-break-before` and `page-break-after`.

The values you'll use for this are `auto`, which is default and `always`. Auto means that the page will break before or after the element (depending on which method you used) if necessary. Always will always force a page break before or after the element.

A note, there are other values available, however I believe these are the only ones which work cross-browser.

Comment: Oh right, so page-break-before/after actually works in all browsers? I thought it was only IE and Firefox. I will try to test it out tomorrow and will let you know

Comment: IE and Firefox are the only ones that fully support it. ie. They accept all of the values such as `left` and `right`. All browsers accept `auto` and `always`